# Conditionally Execute test() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When using the Flutter `test` and `drive` options, can we control the execution of certain test based on the results from the previous ones ? We have a `skip` option in the test. However, I was unable to find anyway to check whether a previous test passed in the program. For example :

```dart
    void main() {
      group('Group A', () {
        FlutterDriver driver;

        // Connect to the Flutter driver before running any tests.
        setUpAll(() async {
          driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
        });

        // Close the connection to the driver after the tests have completed.
        tearDownAll(() async {
          if (driver != null) {
            driver.close();
          }
        });

        test('Test A', () async {
        });

        test('Test B', () async {
        });

        test('Test C', () async {
        });
      });
        }
```

My question is , how can I skip the execution of B and C if A failed and how can I skip the execution of group B id group A tests failed ?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be an explicit way to declare test dependencies, but you could keep track of which tests have passed, and use that information to skip subsequent tests conditionally, e.g.

```dart
final passed = <String>{};

test("a", () {
  expect(1 + 1, 3);
  passed.add("a");
});

test("b", () {
  expect(2 + 2, 5);
}, skip: !passed.containsAll(["a"]));
```

Comment: note this works & skips the test, but confusingly it still prints the test name and a tick in the debugger console